# Testing email sending (test pass even without settings and for garbage emails)

Tags: django

I've just tried testing the sending of emails. Well, test pass whereas I have not assigned anything in settings. This was assumed to be TDD. The next step would be assigning of EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_HOST_USER,
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_USE_TLS, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, SERVER_EMAIL.

Well, the test pass. **I can't catch how to test automatically whether the above mentioned settings are correct.**

Below are my tests. Thank you in advance for a kick here.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core import mail
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class GeneralTest(TestCase):

    def test_send_email(self):        

        number_of_emails_sent = send_mail('Subject here', 
                                          'Here is the message.', 
                                          'from@example.com',
                                          ['to@example.com'], 
                                          fail_silently=False)        
        self.assertEqual(number_of_emails_sent, 1)

    def test_send_email_1(self):
         mail.send_mail(
             'Subject here', 'Here is the message.',
             'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'],
             fail_silently=False,
         )
         pdb.set_trace()
         self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
         self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Subject here')
```

Comment: Could you not have removed that commented-out code before posting?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, pardon for that. It was the second test. Now I have shaped it as another test instead of a commented out one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's test runner automatically redirects emails sent during tests to a fake email backend.

> If any of your Django views send email using Django’s email functionality, you probably don’t want to send email each time you run a test using that view. For this reason, Django’s test runner automatically redirects all Django-sent email to a dummy outbox. This lets you test every aspect of sending email – from the number of messages sent to the contents of each message – without actually sending the messages.
>
> Source: [Django documentation, Testing tools, Email services](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#email-services)

You can use the `mail.outbox` variable to check that the messages you would otherwise have sent are correct.

In your example, you could check that `mail.outbox` contains a single EmailMessage with a subject of 'Subject here', but it would make more sense to run the part of your application that email instead, and test that.

If you want to send an actual email as part of your test, you can pass a real backend in the `connection` argument to `send_mail`.

Comment: I did test the outbox. Maybe I don't understand something, but I did prepare test_send_email_1. This test passes whereas the project definitely can't send emails.

Comment: Both your tests just confirm that Django's dummy backend works. If you want to send a real email as part of your test (you probably don't!), you can use a different backend. If you want to debug why your application can't send email, double-check your configuration, send an email from your actual application and work from there.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to change the backend. Though I don't understand why should I need the confirmation that the dummy backend works.